# How to get number from a div on button click?

Tags: javascript

I am adding two numbers and the sum is placed in a hidden div. I have a button and when i click on it I want to get that number from div. how can I do that? thx!

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var _nmr1 = document.getElementById("txtNmr1").value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            var _nmr2 = document.getElementById("txtNmr2").value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

            var nmr1 = parseInt(_nmr1);
            var nmr2 = parseInt(_nmr2);
            var sum = nmr1 + nmr2;

            document.getElementById("hiddenSum").innerText = sum;

        });

        function checkAnswer() {

             var getDiv = document.getElementById("hiddenSum");
            document.write(getDiv); //returns: [object HTMLDivElement]
        }

<div id="hiddenSum" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `innerText` write  `document.write(getDiv.innerText)` to read text from that div that's why `[object HTMLDivElement]` is returning, because getDiv is a `dom object` of that div and you just need `innerText` property of that. i hope will this make sense for you :)

```
function checkAnswer() {

     var getDiv = document.getElementById("hiddenSum");
    document.write(getDiv.innerText); //this will return text inside div: 
}
```